# How do i get rid of the division by zero php error in this plugin?

Tags: php

How do I get rid of the division by zero php warning in this plugin ?

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/fortduby/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cp_giveaway_n_bets/shortcodes/lottery1.php on line 472

```
$cb_lottery_point_entries_left = round(($cp_point_entry_results / $cb_point_entry_limit) * 100);
```

Comment: Check the `$cb_point_entry_limit` value by echoing out...and make sure it is correct or not..

Comment: It really depends on what the behavior *should* be when cb_point_entry_limit is 0.  What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Don't perform the calculation when `$cb_point_entry_limit` is zero.

Comment: thanks matt ball. this actually did it. i was so focused on this being a conflict with coding in my theme that I didn't realize this was caused by limiting a calculation while actively running a live giveaway. many thanks

Comment: @user1778755 - if this solved your problem don't forget to +1 and mark as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to whichever makes sense of these two in your case

```
$cb_lottery_point_entries_left = 0;
if ($cb_point_entry_limit != 0) {
  $cb_lottery_point_entries_left = round(($cp_point_entry_results / $cb_point_entry_limit) * 100);
}
```

Or

```
if ($cb_point_entry_limit != 0) {
  $cb_lottery_point_entries_left = round(($cp_point_entry_results / $cb_point_entry_limit) * 100);
} else {
  $cb_lottery_point_entries_left = $cp_point_entry_results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
($cb_point_entry_limit > 0) ? round(($cp_point_entry_results / $cb_point_entry_limit) * 100) : 0
```